# Is a defaulted constructor/assignment noexcept/constexpr by default?

Tags: c++, c++11, c++14

So, my question is simple:

Is there any point in specifying a defaulted class constructor as `noexcept` or `constexpr` (or any other thing you could thing of)?

```
struct foo
{
   foo() = default;
   // vs
   constexpr foo() noexcept = default;

   // same thing would apply for copy/move ctors and assignment operators
};
```

Would the two behave the same way?

Does it depend on whether the class is POD? 
For example with the above example both would behave the same way, while if for example I had a private member `std::vector<int> v = { 1, 2, 3, 4 };` which uses in-class assignment, `foo() = default;` would by default not be `noexcept` and not `constexpr`.

By writing `foo() = default;` does the compiler just pick the best version: `noexcept` if possible and `constexpr` if possible, etc?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

[[dcl.fct.def.default]/2-3](http://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.fct.def.default#2):

> 2 An explicitly-defaulted function that is not defined as deleted may
>   be declared `constexpr` only if it would have been implicitly declared
>   as `constexpr`. If a function is explicitly defaulted on its first
>   declaration,
>
> - it is implicitly considered to be `constexpr` if the implicit declaration would be, and,
> - it has the same exception specification as if it had been implicitly declared ([except.spec]).
>
> 3 If a function that is explicitly defaulted is declared with an
>   *exception-specification* that is not compatible ([except.spec]) with
>   the exception specification of the implicit declaration, then
>
> - if the function is explicitly defaulted on its first declaration, it is defined as deleted;
> - otherwise, the program is ill-formed.

In other words, `foo() = default;`, which is necessarily the first declaration of `foo`'s default constructor, will be "`constexpr` if possible" and "`noexcept` if possible". Explicitly writing `constexpr` and `noexcept` is still useful; it means "yell at me if it can't be `constexpr`/`noexcept`".

Comment: Think it will be helpful to explain to folks that the syntax for that is `foo() noexcept = default` as seen at https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/noexcept_spec

Comment: Visual Studio adds a `noexcept(true)` specification to compiler-provided special member functions as well as user-provided destructors and deallocators, unless a contained member or base class has a destructor that is `noexcept(false)`.  See [https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/zc-implicitnoexcept-implicit-exception-specifiers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/zc-implicitnoexcept-implicit-exception-specifiers).  Not sure about compiler-provided assignment operators.