# Custom type in std::atomic

Tags: c++, constructor, atomic, copy-constructor, stdatomic

I've put a custom class `Unit` in an `std::atomic`. Class looked as follows with a default constructor

```
namespace Base
{
    template <typename T, typename R, typename D>
    class Unit
    {
    public: 
        constexpr Unit() = default;
    private:
        T m_Value;
    };
}
```

It used to work fine until I noticed I forgot to initialize the only member of my class to zero in the default constructor. Therefore I removed the `= default` and provided an implementation of the constructor

```
template <typename T, typename R, typename D>
constexpr Unit<T, R, D>::Unit() :
    m_Value(T(0))
{   }
```

Now I am getting a compiler error:

`Error C2280 'std::atomic<Base::Unit>::atomic(void) noexcept': attempting to reference a deleted function`

My hunch was that that's because of the fact that I now provide a custom constructor, which causes the default copy constructor to no longer be implicit defined.

So, I added this as well to the class declaration

```
Unit(const Unit<T, R, D>& U) = default;
```

However, I'm getting the same error. I'm not sure what I could be. I'm not sure which deleted function the compiler is referring to.

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: `std::atomic<T>` only works on trivially-copyable `T`.  `.load()` returns the whole object by value.

Comment: I don't see any mention of `std::atomic` in this code.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The issue here is the exception guarantee of your type.  [Per this post/reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36161188/is-a-defaulted-constructor-assignment-noexcept-constexpr-by-default) your default constructor is noexcept.  When you add your own, you do not provide an exception specification so it is not `noexcept`.  What you need to do is add that to your default constructor since `std::atomic`'s default constructor is marked as `noexcept`

```
namespace Base
{
    template <typename T, typename R, typename D>
    class Unit
    {
    public:
        constexpr Unit() noexcept;
    private:
        T m_Value;
    };

    template <typename T, typename R, typename D>
    constexpr Unit<T, R, D>::Unit() noexcept :
        m_Value(T(0))
    {   }
}

int main() 
{
    std::atomic<Base::Unit<int, int, int>> foo;
}
```

Comment: Ah, I see. Indeed fixed. When providing an atomic with a class whose constructor is potentially throwing, does that cause atomic( const atomic& ) = delete to be called (and thus, throwing the error above)

Comment: @ben, it causes `std::atomic<Base::Unit>::atomic(void) noexcept` to be called but it can't because the type could throw.  The type you give to `std::atomic` needs to be trivially copyable and `noexcept` default constructable, of you want to default construct one.

Answer (score 4):

One workaround is to drop the constructor and use [default member initializers](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/data_members#Member_initialization):

```
template<class T>
struct Unit {
    T value = 0;
};

int main() {
    std::atomic<Unit<int>> a;
    std::atomic<Unit<int>> b = {{1}};
}
```