# Atomic member variable

Tags: c++, initialization, member, stdatomic

We are supposed to declare the private member variable trackerCoordinates as an atomic.
The .h was originally written like:

```
class Missile : public Attack, public Sea::Coordinates {
    private:
        bool hit = false;
        
        Sea::FCoordinates trackerCoordinates;
```

I've tried to use the std::atomic like this:

```
class Missile : public Attack, public Sea::Coordinates {
    private:
        bool hit = false;
        
        std::atomic<Sea::FCoordinates> trackerCoordinates;
```

Now, in the accompanying .cpp, in line 3, there's a new error, which gets resolved by undoing the std::atomic declaration.

```
Missile::Missile(Coordinates const & coordinates)
    : Coordinates(coordinates),
    trackerCoordinates(-1.f,-1.f) -- this line
    {
    }
```

The error says:

> No matching constructor for initialization of 'std::atomicSea::FCoordinates' (aka 'atomic<TCoordinates>')

I do not know why that error happens and how to resolve it.
A bit more information: FCoordinates is a typedef of TCoordinates, which is supposed
to create coordinates given as a parameter like `(x,y)`, and the TCoordinates constructor is noexcept declared.

Thanks in Advance for any help.

Comment: Unrelated: Why is `Missile` inheriting from `Coordinates`? A missile isn't a coordinate, is it?

Comment: The [constructor of `std::atomic`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/atomic/atomic/atomic) does not forward its arguments to the constructor of the element type. It expects a single fully-built element instead. E.g. `trackerCoordinates(Sea::FCoordinates(-1.f,-1.f))`

Comment: Also, this should pass: `static_assert(std::is_trivially_copyable_v<TCoordinates> && std::is_copy_constructible_v<TCoordinates> && std::is_move_constructible_v<TCoordinates> && std::is_copy_assignable_v<TCoordinates> && std::is_move_assignable_v<TCoordinates>, "");`

Comment: Not a duplicate, but closest I've found so far is [Custom type in std::atomic](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52669095) which does show calling the `T` constructor to get a value to pass to the `atomic<T>` constructor.