# std::variant modification in constexpr

Tags: c++, c++17, constexpr, variant

Consider the following two programs:

```
#include<variant>
#include<iostream>

constexpr auto f() {
    using T = std::variant<bool, int>;
    T t(false);
    t = T(true);
    return std::get<bool>(t);
}

template<auto V> 
void print() { std::cout << V << "\n"; }

int main() {
    print<f()>();
}
```

and

```
#include<variant>
#include<iostream>

constexpr auto f() {
    using T = std::variant<bool, int>;
    T t(false);
    t = T(42);
    return std::get<int>(t);
}

template<auto V> 
void print() { std::cout << V << "\n"; }

int main() {
    print<f()>();
}
```

GCC compiles both of these and outputs the expected results. Clang does not compile any of them with the following error message in both cases:

```
<source>:4:16: error: constexpr function never produces a constant expression [-Winvalid-constexpr]
constexpr auto f() {
               ^
<source>:7:7: note: non-constexpr function 'operator=' cannot be used in a constant expression
    t = T(42);
      ^
/opt/compiler-explorer/gcc-8.2.0/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/8.2.0/../../../../include/c++/8.2.0/variant:1095:16: note: declared here
      variant& operator=(variant&&) = default;
```

Are the two programs well-formed? If not, why?

Also if they are not well-formed, is the error message Clang gives appropriate? According to [[variant.assign]](http://eel.is/c++draft/variant.assign) the move assignment operator should be `constexpr`.

Furthermore according to [(7.4)](http://eel.is/c++draft/variant.variant#variant.assign-7.4) the assignment in the second example should behave equivalent to `emplace<int>(...)` which is not declared `constexpr` ([[variant.mod]](http://eel.is/c++draft/variant.variant#variant.mod)). Does this imply the second example is ill-formed because the template argument cannot be evaluated as constant expression or does the wording allow/require this behavior?

EDIT:

Based on the comments it seems that Clang compiles and ouputs the correct results if libc++ is used and the error occurs only with libstdc++. Is this an incompatibility between the standard library and compiler?

On https://godbolt.org/:

Works in both cases:

- GCC 8.2.0 "-std=c++17"
- Clang 7.0.0 "-std=c++17 -stdlib=libc++"

Does not work in either case:

- Clang 7.0.0 "-std=c++17"

Comment: cannot reproduce; which versions of g++ and clang++ are you using?

Comment: What if you use `-stdlib=libc++`

Comment: Looks like your library has a bug as `variant& operator=(variant&&) = default;` should be `constexpr variant& operator=(variant&&) = default;`

Comment: clang accepts it with libc++ [Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/Q4MwhH).

Comment: Show what compilation flags you're using (especially those that select C++ standards version to use).

Comment: GCC 8.2.0 and Clang 7.0.0 on https://godbolt.org/ and https://wandbox.org/ for output test. I have not tested libc++, flags are `-Wall -Wextra -std=c++17`.

Comment: sorry but... compilig your second program with clang++ 7.0.0 ("clang++ prog.cc -Wall -Wextra -std=c++17 -pedantic-errors") in wandbox, all goes well. No error also with the first one.

Comment: @NathanOliver According to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36161188/is-a-defaulted-constructor-assignment-noexcept-constexpr-by-default it might be implicitly `constexpr` depending on the context. Then I still don't see why GCC and Clang would interpret it differently.

Comment: @max66 Yes, sorry. I did not test it there with clang, because clang already failed to compile on godbolt. So it seems this is an incompatibility between clang and libstdc++?

Comment: Interesting. Clang seems to know that move assignment is trivial. I wonder why it  thinks a trivial function is not constexpr.

Comment: Not an answer but similar [clang bug report](https://bugs.llvm.org/show_bug.cgi?id=38526)

Comment: Using VC++ 2017 with /std:c++17 Both programs compile and outputs the expected results.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This looks like a clang bug [we can see from the libstdc++ variant header](https://github.com/gcc-mirror/gcc/blob/gcc-8_2_0-release/libstdc%2B%2B-v3/include/std/variant) that the move assignment operator is indeed not marked constexpr:

```
variant& operator=(variant&&) = default;
```

but a defaulted and implicitly defined move assignment operator can still be constexpr, we can see this from [[class.copy.assign]p10](http://eel.is/c++draft/class.copy.assign#10) (*emphasis mine*):

> A copy/move assignment operator for a class X that is defaulted and
>   not defined as deleted is implicitly defined when it is odr-used
>   ([basic.def.odr]) (e.g., when it is selected by overload resolution to
>   assign to an object of its class type), when it is needed for constant
>   evaluation ([expr.const]), or when it is explicitly defaulted after
>   its first declaration. The **implicitly-defined copy/move assignment
>   operator is constexpr if**
>
> - (10.1) X is a literal type, and
> - (10.2) the assignment operator selected to copy/move each direct base class subobject is a constexpr function, and
> - (10.3) for each non-static data member of X that is of class type (or array thereof), the assignment operator selected to copy/move that
>     member is a constexpr function.

From what I can can tell the libstdc++ implementation should fit all these cases, it is a literal type, it does not have non static data members and the assignment operator for all its bases should be constexpr as well.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Originally I wanted to primarily know whether both programs are well-formed, see the multiple questions above `EDIT:`. If possible can you answer these as well?

Comment: @user10605163 there are a lot of questions that discuss what is valid in a constexpr function [for example here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34280783/1708801) it quotes the full quote and `f()` is well formed there.