# Conditional noexcept: usecase

Tags: c++, exception

I am currently writing a public library for vector and matrix operations.
My library, as it stands now, only accepts arithmetic types and complex numbers (by using `std::complex<T>`).
Since I value-initialize an array of type T, where T might be `std::complex<T>`, and since `std::complex<T>`'s default constructor is not `noexcept`, I'm wondering whether it is the case to have my default constructor have a conditional noexcept for this single case, so that the constructor is noexcept only when T's default constructor is marked noexcept.
I don't know if that makes any sense; currently, I can't find a reason as to why this might be helpful. But on the other hand, I am completely unaware of what anyone using the library might do with it (they might, perhaps, store multiple Math::Vectors inside a `std::vector` too, I guess?).

So long story short: I'm wondering whether something like this would make sense, to cover the case where `std::complex<T>` is passed:

```cpp
private:
    T math_vector[Size]{}; // T might be std::complex
public:
    constexpr Vector() noexcept(std::is_nothrow_default_constructible_v<T>) = default;
```

Comment: @PepijnKramer Um, most constructors are noexcept.  You must have a noexcept move constructor if you want `std::vector` to move your elements when growing.  If your class only has an `int` member it is also not going to throw an exception and marking it as noexcept is perfectly fine.

Comment: IIRC I have seen STL containers do this. I should have to recheck though so take this with a grain of salt.

Comment: @NathanOliver Ok I stand corrected. (after checkeing : https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/noexcept_spec)

Comment: But still, I am very unsure whether I'm doing this correctly or if it's needed for std::complex type. Also, I noticed that I have a default value initialization, [[[[ and I forgot whether that takes the precedence over default constructors. Maybe that makes the conditional noexcept useless since it might still throw.]]]]]

EDIT: nevermind. The constructor takes the precedence. So is the approach OK?

Comment: `std::complex` doesn't do dynamic allocation so it's not really needed.

Comment: I see. Should I leave it in case I change the allowed types in the future, or is that considered a bad approach? Thanks for the quick answer, by the way.

Comment: Had to double check t make sure but looks like the default constructor will be implicitly noexcept as long as the members of the class have noexcept default constructors: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36161188/is-a-defaulted-constructor-assignment-noexcept-constexpr-by-default

Comment: Perfect, that makes some sense I guess. I too completely forgot about the default keyword there.

Comment: See the section starting _"...functions declared without noexcept specifier except for..."_ https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/noexcept_spec  which includes _"...default constructors, copy constructors, move constructors that are implicitly-declared or defaulted on their first declaration unless..."_